# Carry data after saving info in database

Tags: c#

How to carry data with like , It wont carry no matter what even if i put it under the " data saved " because i'm trying to do like after data saved in database , " data saved" comes out and it doesnt carry data even if its in the same form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandText = "insert into RegisterItem([Name], [Url],[Description], [Price]) values('" + ItemName.Text + "','" + ItemUrl.Text + "','" + ItemDescription.Text + "','" + ItemPrice.Text + "')";

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            txtUsername = txtID1;
            ItemName = txtName1;
            ItemDescription = txtDescription1;
            ItemPrice = txtPrice1;

            ItemName.Text = "";
            ItemDescription.Text = "";
            ItemPrice.Text = "";
            connect.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            connect.Close();
        }

        string str = ItemUrl.Text;
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = str;
        //string str = textBox1.Text;
        // Image img = Image.FromFile(str);
        // pictureBox1.Image = img;             
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "carry data"?

Comment: as in textbox=textbox , but it doesnt allow me even when i put it be it below or on top of the button , i think its cause of the command.ExecuteNonQuery(); as i couldnt find any other ways

Comment: I really don't understand what you're saying.  You will have to find a way to clarify your answer. "as in textbox=textbox" makes no sense to me.

Comment: Which part of your code is not working?  Which result are you getting?  What were you expecting?

Comment: Okay as you see below i put  txtUsername = txtID1 , txtUsername is the box i input data , and txtID1 is the textbox that i want the data to carry over , but in the same form .

Comment: So after pressing button , values in txtUsername1 would carry over txtID1(Textbox) , Even when i put under the command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");   it doesn't carry over

Comment: Yeah, because your basically copying the textbox reference to the other variable.

Comment: Yup , but in this situation it doesnt allow me to copy the textbox ref to another varaible , after command.ExecuteNonQuery(); MessageBox.Show("Data Saved") which is after adding in the database

Comment: Why would you copy the textbox ref to another variable?  Is this really what you want?  Are you just trying to copy the textbox content to another variable?

Comment: Yup whats with i want , Then clear it , but i want it to happen after the " data saved" which is after its added into the database

Comment: If that's what you want, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Kinetic , I've copied and it solved , thanks

Comment: Nice, feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to copy the TextBox Text property to another textBox text property, then clear the source textbox value.

```
txtID1.Text = txtUsername.Text;
txtName1.Text = ItemName.Text;
txtDescription1.Text = ItemDescription.Text;
txtPrice1.Text = ItemPrice.Text;

ItemName.Text = "";
ItemDescription.Text = "";
ItemPrice.Text = "";
```

This code can be paste anywhere under `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: Yes , But as i have the content added into the database first then to copy the TextBox Text property to another textBox text property, then clear the source textbox value , but it doesnt allow me to , be it where i put like after the exception

Comment: Is this a question?